# AudioQueue sample values are wrong

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, audioqueue

I need to read audio sample values. I am using for that audioQueue callback (from Apple SpeakHere example):

```
     UInt32 samplesCount = inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioDataBytesCapacity / 2;

    UInt16 *samples = (UInt16 *)inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioData;   

    for (int i=0; i < samplesCount; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", samples[i]); 
    }
```

Values are returned, but when I compare them with graph from audacity, they seems to be wrong:

[image: screen]

Audacity values are from 1 (65535) to -1 (0). So logically first sample value should be 32767, second should be ~50 000 ...

But I recieve other results:

```
    value - position

    65535 - 0
    29501 - 1
    26086 - 2
    63656 - 3
    28477 - 4
    65407 - 5
    36802 - 6
    36546 - 7
    18244 - 8
    17220 - 9

    player settings:

    (Float64) mSampleRate = 44100
    (UInt32) mBytesPerPacket = 2
    (UInt32) mFramesPerPacket = 1
    (UInt32) mBytesPerFrame = 2
    (UInt32) mChannelsPerFrame = 1
    (UInt32) mBitsPerChannel = 16
    (UInt32) mReserved = 0
```

Question - why sample values returned from mAudioData are wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file has a different endianess than your System. You must swap the byte order of each sample. Also the samples are Signed 16 bit integers (SInt16), not UInt16. Therefore the maximum value is 32767 (not 65535) and the minimum value is -32767.

Take a look in ExtendedAudioFile.h and AudioConverter.h for help converting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I already used audio unit example from [link](https://github.com/reinforce-lab/MonoTouch.AudioUnit) and SInt32 to get sample values and it worked for me. Btw, is there difference between SInt16 and UInt16? I mean using UInt16 instead of SInt16 to get values in range from 0 (-32767 in SInt16) to 65535 (32767 in SInt16) is wrong?

Comment: It's ok with me, but you won't see values the same as audacity unless you byte swap and use SInt16.